# QUERY command WHERE parameter not finding match - format error?

Tags: google-sheets

The following command,
=QUERY(J6:O, "Select J,K,L,M,N,O WHERE J= ' " &A2& " ' AND L>= date ' " & text(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd") & " ' AND L<= date ' " & text(C2,"yyyy-mm-dd") & " '  ")
J= not matching values to A2, but when I hard code it into command then it work.
J=211081 is working.
Link to Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G2Hyo3z1xGZ91_838-mLdiP7Tmf0lKEnDJTLtTNreiE/edit?usp=sharing
Purpose: Select J=A2 and L>=B2 and L<=C2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove single quotes 
From   `' " &A2& " '`  to  `" &A2& "`

```
=QUERY(J7:O, "Select J,K,L,M,N,O WHERE J="& $A$2&" AND L>= date '" & text(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND L<= date '" & text(C2,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "'  ")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY(J6:O, "where J = "&A2&" 
                and L >= date ' " & TEXT(B2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
                and L <= date ' " & TEXT(C2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", )
```

if A2 cell and J column contain numeric values so you cant wrap A2 into single quotes. only plain text strings need such wrapping.